# AES decryption and 'invalid pkcs #7 block padding'

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I have this code to try decryption:

```
byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
string key_s = "essasenhaehfraca";

for (int i = 0; i < key_s.size(); i++)
    key[i] = (byte) key_s[i];

string ciphertext = "A506A19333F306AC2C62CBE931963AE7DFCFFA940360A40FFD5DC69B9C2E53AD"
string decryptedtext;

try
{
    ECB_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKey(key, sizeof(key));
    CryptoPP::StringSource(ciphertext, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
                new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext )
            )
    );

}
catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
```

When I execute it, I get the exception
`StreamTransformationFilter: invalid pkcs #7 block padding found`.
I searched and didn't find anything. Someone knows why I get this error? Every example I found in the internet is in this same way and none of them mention this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your Cipher text is hex-encoded.  You need to add a `HexDecoder` to your decryption stream:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(ciphertext, true,
    new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
            new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) ) ) );
```

Comment: That wash the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I think it's because you don't create your key correctly:

```
byte* key_s = (byte*)"essasenhaehfraca";
SecByteBlock key( key_s, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
```

And after that:

```
ECB_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
d.SetKey( key, key.size() );
```

Comment: Here says that no implementation of `SecByteBlock` accept `string` as the first argument.

Comment: @user2748531 and if you change `string` by `byte`: `byte* key_s = "essasenhaehfraca";`?

Comment: `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [17]' to 'byte *`

Comment: @user2748531 `byte* key_s = (byte*)"essasenhaehfraca";`

Comment: Still nothing. `SecByteBlock` says `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'byte *' to 'byte [16]'`. I really don't know why it's not working...

Comment: @user2748531 What is your version of cryptopp?

Comment: It should be the latest: 5.6.2.

Comment: @user2748531 Look at [**this example**](http://ideone.com/g4cNSU). I rewrote the SecByteBlock ctor, and there is no compilation error...

Comment: It didn't work. It gives the same exception... but thanks for the help. Anyone knows some simple example that should work for me to try?

Comment: @user2748531 This sample gives an exception ?

Comment: Yes, when I try to run the program with the key like the example it gives the same exception.